# Which module is related to "Manage orders" (path : admin/commerce/orders)?

Tags: drupal, commerce

I've a commerce kickstart (D7.15) up, everything work well, but the part of orders managing doesn't ...

That's located at this path : `http://website/en/admin/commerce/orders` (`http://website/en#overlay=en/admin/commerce/orders` & `http://website/en?q=admin/commerce/orders` don't work either)

I get this error :

"EntityMetadataWrapperException: Missing data values. in EntityMetadataWrapper->value() (line 83 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc)."

and this message :

"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

The biggest problem is that I've no idea about which module is related to this interface, I need to know, then I could update it and/or try fix it by myself ...

Here the "Commerce" modules enabled :
Cart (commerce_cart) 7.x-1.4
Checkout (commerce_checkout) 7.x-1.4
Commerce (commerce) 7.x-1.4
Commerce Atos Payment method (commerce_atos) 7.x-1.0-beta3+1-dev
Commerce Discount (commerce_discount) 7.x-1.0-alpha1
Commerce Discount Date (commerce_discount_date) 7.x-1.0-alpha1
Commerce UI (commerce_ui) 7.x-1.4
Customer (commerce_customer) 7.x-1.4
Customer UI (commerce_customer_ui) 7.x-1.4
Line Item (commerce_line_item) 7.x-1.4
Line Item UI (commerce_line_item_ui) 7.x-1.4
Order (commerce_order) 7.x-1.4
Order UI (commerce_order_ui)  7.x-1.4
Payment (commerce_payment) 7.x-1.4
Payment UI (commerce_payment_ui) 7.x-1.4
Price (commerce_price)  7.x-1.4
Product (commerce_product) 7.x-1.4
Product Pricing (commerce_product_pricing) 7.x-1.4
Product Pricing UI (commerce_product_pricing_ui) 7.x-1.4
Product Reference (commerce_product_reference) 7.x-1.4
Product UI (commerce_product_ui)  7.x-1.4
Tax (commerce_tax) 7.x-1.4
Tax UI (commerce_tax_ui)  7.x-1.4
Checkout Redirect (commerce_checkout_redirect) 7.x-1.x-dev
Commerce (Product Display Manager) (commerce_pdm) 7.x-1.0-alpha3
Commerce Addressbook (commerce_addressbook) 7.x-2.0-rc3
Commerce Backoffice (commerce_backoffice) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Backoffice Order (commerce_backoffice_order) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Backoffice Product (commerce_backoffice_product) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Checkout Progress (commerce_checkout_progress) 7.x-1.2
Commerce Extra Price Formatters (commerce_extra_price_formatters) 7.x-1.1
Commerce File (commerce_file) 7.x-1.0-beta4+4-dev
Commerce Migrate (commerce_migrate)  7.x-1.0
Commerce Price Savings Formatter (commerce_price_savings_formatter) 7.x-1.3
Commerce Stock (commerce_stock) 7.x-1.1
Flat Rate (commerce_flat_rate) 7.x-1.x-dev
Shipping (commerce_shipping) 7.x-2.0
Shipping UI (commerce_shipping_ui) 7.x-2.0
Commerce Extra (commerce_extra) 7.x-1.0-alpha1+8-dev 
Commerce Extra Address Populate (commerce_extra_address_populate)  7.x-1.0-alpha1+8-dev 
Commerce Extra Login Page (commerce_extra_login_page) 7.x-1.0-alpha1+8-dev 
Commerce Extra Quantity (commerce_extra_quantity)  7.x-1.0-alpha1+8-dev 
Commerce Kickstart Block (commerce_kickstart_block) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Blog (commerce_kickstart_blog) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Checkout Redirect (commerce_kickstart_checkout_redirect) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Comment (commerce_kickstart_comment) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Content UI (commerce_kickstart_content_ui)  7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Menus (commerce_kickstart_menus) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Migrate (commerce_kickstart_migrate) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Order (commerce_kickstart_order)  7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Payment Example (commerce_kickstart_payment) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Reset (commerce_kickstart_reset) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart Search (commerce_kickstart_search) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart service provider (commerce_kickstart_service_provider) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart User (commerce_kickstart_user) 7.x-2.0-rc1
Commerce Features (commerce_features) 7.x-1.0-rc1
Commerce Kickstart help (commerce_kickstart_help) 7.x-2.0-rc1

Here the "Order" modules enabled :
Order (commerce_order) 7.x-1.3+40-dev
Order UI (commerce_order_ui) 7.x-1.3+40-dev
(There are some "Order" modules already in the list above.)

Please halp me :(

Thank you .
Regards

Comment: The commerce_order module defines a View for that path. First step would be to edit that view at `admin/structure/views/view/commerce_orders/edit` and see if you work out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with an order module. The problem will lie with one of the other modules that hook into the order process. You have quite a large number of commerce modules and finding the offending module may be difficult.
I do not use commerce kickstart though and am only really taking a guess. I would try posting this on the drupal commerce website http://www.drupalcommerce.org/